# Get list of players from server

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

I would like to be able to get a complete player list from a server, either by using server IP or a player that is currently logged into server.

The game I want to do this specifically for is Ark Survival Evolved.

I have looked at the Steam Web API documentation and cannot see any endpoint with this data however in the steam client this is all viewable with "view game info".

Is it possible to do this via a Steam API or do I have to figure out how to manually handshake with the game server to retrieve this data.  I have searched high and low but cannot find the answer.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you look in steam under servers you can see you can filter on "Ark Survival Evolved." so you can most likly query the gameserver with this https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries or use steam condenser API

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to get the information using the Valve [A2S Protocol](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries), at least for some servers.

You can use the the [python-valve library](https://github.com/Holiverh/python-valve) to query the server.

I have written an IRC plugin for Supybot/Limnoria that implements this check. You can see an example of it's use in the [code](https://github.com/johnfzc/Ark-Supybot-plugin/blob/master/Ark/plugin.py#L59).

Comment: Some services show game chat on Source servers. Do you know how to query the chat messages?